# Unity 3D Creating a New Project

Tags: project, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Unity 3D new Project. But i am not able to import the Standard Assets.unityPackage as it is not available in my installation. Looks like i just have the Mobile version of the same.

How can i use the Desktop version as i will need to test the project on desktop and not on mobile device ?

Is there any way i can download it from some where and import it into the program.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pro only packages come under the standardAssets. Instead of giving it under a single file the Unity 3D people have segregated it into different files. So, while creating the project create using all those pro only assets and for character control prefabs tick the character controller package at the beginning.